# How to pass each id from JSP to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

In our JSP application, we are creating HTML buttons in a loop.

```
<%for(int i=0;i<5;i++){%> 
    <input type="button" class="btn-success btn-rounded" id ="?????" onclick="jsfunction()">
<%}%>
```

I would like to pass each button's `id` to JavaScript function, but it doesn't work.
Currently, the first button's `id` is passed. How to pass each button's `id` to JavaScript?

Comment: Need more context to answer this question.  Are just storing the id passed to the JS method or something else.

Comment: @BalusC When passed to js it doesnt works for every id.

Comment: Why do you want `Id`? I'd say better send `this` as a parameter in `jsfunction()` , something like this `jsfunction(this)`. and use it in your function.

Comment: @AKS123 Do check the answer and let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use Scriplet, use JSTL.

JSP

```
<%for(int i=0;i<5;i++){%> "<input type="button" class="btn-success btn-rounded dynamicButtons" onclick="jsmethod(this)"> <%}%>
```

Js code

```
function jsmethod(button){
   alert("Hey"+button+" is clicked");
   // buisness logic goes here
}
```

[EDIT]
**Using scriplet**

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="5">
   <input type="button" class="btn-success btn-rounded dynamicButtons" onclick="jsmethod(this)">
</c:forEach>
```

do check http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm

**PS: Scriplets are evil**